# Maps In Salesforce using Nested Query

Tags: map

I have a Nested Query Like this:

```
list<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id, OrderId,Product_Group__c,OrderType__c FROM OrderItems) FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :setOrderitemId)];
```

I want to collect Orderitem object id,not orderid using seperate Map:

I have tried Like this

```
**`Map setid,Listorderitem collectingids = new Map setid,Listorderitem ();`**

collectingids.put(orders.orderitemid,new Listorderitem());
```

**But it is Showing Error:
Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: ListOrder ,**

**How to Rectify the Error,Please Anyone Guide Me for the Answer**

```
    trigger updateorderpricebookidofferrule1 on Orderitem (after insert) 
    {
        list<orderitem> addinglist = new list<orderitem>();
        set<decimal> offerLevels = new Set<decimal>();
        Set<Id> pricebookIds = new Set<Id>();
        set<string> productgroups = new set<string>();
        set<string> ordertypes = new set<string>();
        Map<String, List<order>> offerRuleMap = new Map<String, List<order>>();
        Map<string,List<orderitem>> collectingids = new Map<string,List<orderitem>>();
        set<Id> setOrderitemId = new set<Id>();

        for(Orderitem objOrderitem: Trigger.New)
        {
            setOrderitemId.add(objOrderitem.orderid);

             collectingids.put(objOrderitem.id,new List<orderitem>());

        }

        list<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id, OrderId,Product_Group__c,OrderType__c FROM OrderItems) FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :setOrderitemId)];

        for(Order ord :orders) {

            for(Orderitem ord2:ord.OrderItems){

                offerLevels.add(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c);

                productgroups.add(ord2.Product_Group__c);

                ordertypes.add(ord2.OrderType__c);
                if(!offerRuleMap.containsKey(String.valueof(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) + ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.OrderType__c )) {
                    offerRuleMap.put(String.valueOf(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c) +  ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.OrderType__c , new List<Order>());
                    offerRuleMap.get(String.valueOf(ord.Order_Qty_Multiplier__c)  + ord2.Product_Group__c + ord2.OrderType__c ).add(ord); 
                }
            }
        }

        for(Offer_Rule__c rule :[SELECT Id, Offer_Level__c, Pricebook2__c,Product_Group__c,Type__c FROM Offer_Rule__c where Offer_Level__c IN :offerLevels  and Product_Group__c IN:productgroups and Type__c IN:ordertypes]) {


                    **for(orderitem i2 :collectingids.get(string))** {
                        Orderitem rs = new orderitem(id=i2.id);
                        rs.Offer_Rule__c = rule.id ; 
                        addinglist.add(rs);

                    }
                }


        update addinglist;
    }

The Line where i have Marked as Bold I am Got Strucked Thats Why I am asking
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query

```
list<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, Status, Pricebook2Id, Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, (SELECT Id, OrderId,Product_Group__c,OrderType__c FROM OrderItems) FROM Order WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :setOrderitemId)];
```

Returns the Order Object with a LIST of orderitems as the subquery

To access them you would:

```
for(Order o : list<Order> orders = [SELECT 
                                        Id, Status, Pricebook2Id,  
                                        Order_Qty_Multiplier__c, 
                                        (SELECT Id, OrderId,Product_Group__c,OrderType__c 
                                        FROM OrderItems) 
                                      FROM Order 
                                    WHERE Id IN (SELECT OrderId 
                                         FROM OrderItem WHERE Id IN :setOrderitemId)]){
     for(OrderItem oi : o.OrderItems){
         //do something with each order ID
     }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to do what you need in the location marked. Each oi will be an order item related to the order. If all you need are order Items why not just directly query the order items, why query the order and subquery the items?

Comment: My Problem is in trigger for bulk code In order having one Custom Fields and orderitem object contain two custom fields if it three  Matches with the another custom object, then the Particular custom Object Name should be updated in Orderitem For that only i am asking using Map @Eric

Comment: This is My Bulk Code

Comment: I believe your question keeps changing. My answer I believe answer your original question. If you have another you should start a new question. This forum is not ideal for a long ever changing discussion. Have you even attempted to take any part of my answer and try it?